# How to move the axis on a 3d model

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

A few days into 3d models and I can't figure out how to move an axis so I can start my rotations.  for example....   I want to tilt X at 30 degrees and then I will be lined up to do each axis rotations.  If I rotate X to 30 degrees it throws off Y and Z rotations. Any examples of how to do this in code behind?   The closest example I found was in the Manipulator demo but it doesn't show the code on how the manipulator works.

[image]

```
  private Transform3DGroup GetTransforms(Model3D model)
    {
        var transforms = new Transform3DGroup();
        // Rotation around X
        transforms.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 0)));
        // Rotation around Y 
        transforms.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 0)));
        // Rotation around Z
        transforms.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 0)));
        // Translate transform (if required)
        transforms.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform3D());
        model.Transform = transforms;
        return transforms;
    }

 private void SetRotation(double amountX, double amountY, double amountZ, Model3D model, Point3D center)
    {
        // Suppose we have a function that gives us all the transforms
        // applied to this object
        var transforms = GetTransforms(model);
        var translation = transforms.Children[3];

        // Suppose GetCenter() obtains the center point of an object
        // in Point3D format
        var translatedCenter = translation.Transform(center);

        if (!(transforms.Children[0] is RotateTransform3D rotX)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rotX));
        if (!(transforms.Children[1] is RotateTransform3D rotY)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rotY));
        if (!(transforms.Children[2] is RotateTransform3D rotZ)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rotZ));

        // Set the center point of transformation to the translated center of the object
        rotX.CenterX = rotY.CenterX = rotZ.CenterX = translatedCenter.X;
        rotX.CenterY = rotY.CenterY = rotZ.CenterY = translatedCenter.Y;
        rotX.CenterZ = rotY.CenterZ = rotZ.CenterZ = translatedCenter.Z;

        // Apply the angle amounts
        ((AxisAngleRotation3D) rotX.Rotation).Angle = amountX;
        ((AxisAngleRotation3D) rotY.Rotation).Angle = amountY;
        ((AxisAngleRotation3D) rotZ.Rotation).Angle = amountZ;
    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the mathematics transformations? i.e.: scaling, rotation, translation?

Comment: Next: you need to figure out if you are rotating the object, or the camera. This is a significant difference.

Comment: not really, but learning the basics...  my model is simple and I use AxisAngleRotation3D on child items within the ModelVisual3D with sliders.

Comment: If you know about rotation and translation you can see whats happening and pinpoint the issue. It really simple actually: every repositioning of an object consist of 3 steps (assuming the object is in the center): 1) rotate object around axis, 2) shif the object along axis, 3) scale object appropriate. So although I don't have any thing to show you, my guess is that your rotation doesn't take place in the center(origin) of what you are trying to rotate.

Comment: My camera is still, from the front.  I can rotate the model on each axis. but rotating axis  doesnt change where the others rotate. Ie. Z is always up no matter what the angles of the other axis are at.

Comment: Imagine my model as a stick that's pointing up.  My center point is in the middle of the stick.  If I rotate the stick X 90 the Z is looking at the stick sideways and spinning it longways.  I need Z to move along with the rotation of X.  I hope this make sense.

Comment: Maybe some screenshots will help ;-)

Comment: added a pic...  Current is the state I can do.  Future is want I want.  If I rotate Y to match Future then Z doesn't move along with Y, it stays pointing north up so my model rotates odd on Z.

Comment: `but rotating axis doesn't change where the others rotate`=> So you're not performing a real rotation. Can you share your code for this part? Anyway, I strongly suggest that you move and rotate the camera and not the model... that's much much more easy to perform.

Comment: added 2 methods I use.  I"m guessing i need to use some sort of Marix3d.